# How to do function composition in Lean 4?

Tags: functional-programming, function-composition, lean

If I have two functions `f` and `g`, in Haskell I can [compose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) them by writing `g.f`. How do I do the same thing in Lean 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbol in Lean is the unicode `∘`, which is notation for [`Function.comp`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Init/Prelude.html#Function.comp).

Comment: What's the shortcut to enter this symbol in VSCode?

Comment: \comp, \circ should both work, iirc

Comment: is there a notation for forward function composition ?  aka f >> g = \x -> g (f x)

Comment: @nicolas I used `infixr:90 " ⧁ " => fun f g ↦ Function.comp g f` but the chosen symbol might not be the best